# how to get specific length of integer from user?

Tags: c, int

How can I get specific length of integer value from user? I have a piece of code for creating user account in C. Which requires `char user_name[30]` and 4-digits of `int pin`. I want to confirm that user has entered 4 digits of pin other wise give an error to the user. How can I do this?

Comment: A PIN code is a string, not an integer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That depends on the country in quesiton. Not universal.

Comment: @BlueMoon: The user hasn't specified any constraints, so in the general case, it's not an integer.

Comment: Isn't the `int` in the question a constrain? @OliCharlesworth

Comment: @alk: possibly. But my guess is that it's a mistake. (To clarify, in referring to the leading-zero issue.)

Comment: @alk There are countries/banks where it's a fixed to certain such 8/10 digits (so no leading zeros or even differing lengths). As a programmer, I'd prefer to handle as a string though, as it's rarely necessary to perform any "operations" on it ;-)

Comment: Consider specifying what is used to separate the `user_name` from the `pin`, spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking the input as a character array and then apply strlen

```
pin = scanf("%s",pin_buffer);
len = strlen(pin);
```

then check if len == 4 or not and display the message accordigly!

Answer (score 1):

Read a signed integer from the user, substract `1000` and test the result for being  `>0` also subtract `10000` and test the result from being `<0`.

---

**Update**

Better: Just test the integer read in for being `>=0` and `<=9999`.

Comment: Won't work if the code starts with one or more `0`s (but then this is a fundamental problem with using an `int` for this).

Comment: Yes, I also don't like this answer. Deleting ... @OliCharlesworth

Comment: Switch my mind, as your comment on this "bad" answer makes it somehow meaningful ... ;-) @OliCharlesworth

Answer (score 0):

Suggest `fgets()/sscanf()`

To read a `char user_name[30]` and 4-digits of `int pin` (which may include 0 digits):

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOErrorOrEOF();

user_name[30];
unsigned pin;
int n1, n2;

int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%29s %n%u%n", user_name, &n1, &pin, &n2);
if (cnt != 2 || (n2-n1 != 4) || buf[n2] != '\n' || pin > 9999) Handle_BadInput();
else GoodInput(user_name, pin);
```

By consuming leading spaces with `" "` before `"%n%u%n"`, code will only consume digits.
Some systems allow a `'-'` with `"%u"`, hence the `pin > 9999` test.
The 2 `"%n"` allow code to collect the offest before/after `"%u"` to insure 4 digits.